# Golang serve static files from memory

Tags: http, static, go, assets

I have a quick question about serving files in Go. There is the great timesaving FileServer handler, but for my use case, I only have 2 or 3 files (js and css) that go with my app and I dont want to complicate the deployment to have to think about those.

Do you think there is an easy way to build those couple of files into the binary and serve them from there. For example base64 encode the data of the files as constants and server the files from the constants. This would work in its most simple form, but I dont want to go through the pain of doing everything that a file server does (headers, expiries, mime-types, etc) on my own. So would there be an easy way to bake those static files into the binary in some form and serve them that way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "[go.rice](https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice)" package takes care of this for you - embedding resources in your binaries, and providing an http.FileSystem implementation.

Answer (score 21):

The `FileServer` requires a `FileSystem` object in its constructor. Usually, you would provide something based on `http.Dir` to make that `FileSystem` for you from the actual file system, but nothing prevents you from implementing your own:

```
package main

import "os"
import "time"
import "net/http"

type InMemoryFS map[string]http.File

// Implements FileSystem interface
func (fs InMemoryFS) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    if f, ok := fs[name]; ok {
        return f, nil
    }
    panic("No file")
}

type InMemoryFile struct {
    at   int64
    Name string
    data []byte
    fs   InMemoryFS
}

func LoadFile(name string, val string, fs InMemoryFS) *InMemoryFile {
    return &InMemoryFile{at: 0,
        Name: name,
        data: []byte(val),
        fs:   fs}
}

// Implements the http.File interface
func (f *InMemoryFile) Close() error {
    return nil
}
func (f *InMemoryFile) Stat() (os.FileInfo, error) {
    return &InMemoryFileInfo{f}, nil
}
func (f *InMemoryFile) Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error) {
    res := make([]os.FileInfo, len(f.fs))
    i := 0
    for _, file := range f.fs {
        res[i], _ = file.Stat()
        i++
    }
    return res, nil
}
func (f *InMemoryFile) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    i := 0
    for f.at < int64(len(f.data)) && i < len(b) {
        b[i] = f.data[f.at]
        i++
        f.at++
    }
    return i, nil
}
func (f *InMemoryFile) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error) {
    switch whence {
    case 0:
        f.at = offset
    case 1:
        f.at += offset
    case 2:
        f.at = int64(len(f.data)) + offset
    }
    return f.at, nil
}

type InMemoryFileInfo struct {
    file *InMemoryFile
}

// Implements os.FileInfo
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) Name() string       { return s.file.Name }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) Size() int64        { return int64(len(s.file.data)) }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) Mode() os.FileMode  { return os.ModeTemporary }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) ModTime() time.Time { return time.Time{} }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) IsDir() bool        { return false }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) Sys() interface{}   { return nil }

const HTML = `<html>
    Hello world !
</html>
`

const CSS = `
p {
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
} 
`

func main() {
    FS := make(InMemoryFS)
    FS["foo.html"] = LoadFile("foo.html", HTML, FS)
    FS["bar.css"] = LoadFile("bar.css", CSS, FS)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(FS))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

This implementation is *very* buggy at best, and you should probably never ever use it, but it should show you how the `FileSystem` interface can be implemented for arbitrary 'files'.

A more credible (and certainly less dangerous) implementation of something similar is available [here](https://code.google.com/r/rsc-go13nacl/source/browse/src/pkg/syscall/fs_nacl.go). This is the one used to [fake the filesystem](http://blog.golang.org/playground) on Go playground, so it should be a good reference (much better than mine anyway).

Whether it is simpler to reimplement this `FileSystem` interface or a custom `FileServer` as other suggested, is entirely up to you and your project ! I suspect however that for serving a couple of predefined files, rewriting the serving part might be easier than emulating a full file-system.

Answer (score 5):

It is not very difficult to do what you request. You don't have to base64 encode it or anything (it will just make it harder for you to edit.).

Below is an example of how to output a javascript file with correct mime type:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const jsFile = `alert('Hello World!');`

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/file.js", JsHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func JsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Getting the headers so we can set the correct mime type
    headers := w.Header()
    headers["Content-Type"] = []string{"application/javascript"}
    fmt.Fprint(w, jsFile)
}
```

Comment: i explicityle mention, i want to leave the content types and other headers to the file server and not handle them manually.

Comment: But if you aren't using a file system, then you can't leave it to the file server to handle the mime types.

Comment: @eduncan911 please refer to accepted answer, you can by using this kind of solution, that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I would store the files in variable as plain text.
Something like this:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

var files = map[string]string{}

func init() {
        files["style.css"] = `
/* css file content */
body { background-color: pink; }
`
}

func init() {
        files["index.html"] = `
<!-- Html content -->
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head><body>Hello world!</body></html>
`
}

func main() {
        for fileName, content := range files {
                contentCpy := content
                http.HandleFunc("/"+fileName, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", contentCpy)
                })
        }

        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

That way, it is pretty easy to have your makefile or build script so something like:

`` for file in index.html style.css; do echo "package main\nfunc init() { files[\"$file\"] = \`$(cat $file)\` }" | gofmt -s > $file.go; done; go build && ./httptest ``

Comment: i mention this solution in my question, but it won't handle headers, content types, etc correctly. I will have to do this all on my own...

Comment: I think http.ResponseWriter handles the content type, headers etc unless you serve something  exotic

Comment: Yes but that would be the case based on the extension of the actual file not based on whats in the file, so if you respond with a string of CSS i dont think it would handle it automatically unless you specify the header.