# Zip FileSystem in Golang

Tags: go, filesystems, zip

I am developing web server in Go and I wish to have all static files in ZIP file.
It looks like I have to implement http.FileSystem interface that will read from ZIP.

Is there such implementation?

I have made one based on 
[Golang serve static files from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595295/golang-serve-static-files-from-memory#21601539)
But these article claims it to be buggy

I found following references that there was work (and commits) to add ZipFileSystem to Golang
https://codereview.appspot.com/4750047

I am wondering if there is good marture implementation of Zip http.FileSystem in Go?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a [zip static](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/cbgb/blob/master/zipstatic.go) thing that does what you're describing. Also has unit tests in case you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: Thank You for sharing your code. I do not understand but your code works and my code works 99%. Some files "hang". Web browser reloads that file permanently. millions times. Log file grows to 1GB. 100MB in minutes. Here is my code. Not sure what may course looping reloads. http://play.golang.org/p/GwInAHbgzG

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [zipfs](https://github.com/spkg/zipfs) package, which serves HTTP from zip files (like Dustin's library), and it also implements the [`http.FileSystem`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem) interface. (With unit tests also).