# Serving a map of strings without 3rd party libraries using http.filesystem in Go (Golang)

Tags: go, embeddedwebserver

I am just starting out with Go and am trying to learn how to build a simple web app without using 3rd party libraries / packages.

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595295/golang-serve-static-files-from-memory) and [this code](https://github.com/mjibson/esc/blob/master/embed/embed.go) as a guideline, I've hacked the following together:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path"
    "time"
)

type StaticFS map[string]*staticFile

type staticFile struct {
    name string
    data []byte
    fs   StaticFS
}

func LoadAsset(name string, data string, fs StaticFS) *staticFile {
    return &staticFile{name: name,
        data: []byte(data),
        fs:   fs}
}

func (fs StaticFS) prepare(name string) (*staticFile, error) {
    f, present := fs[path.Clean(name)]
    if !present {
        return nil, os.ErrNotExist
    }
    return f, nil
}

func (fs StaticFS) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    f, err := fs.prepare(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return f.File()
}

func (f *staticFile) File() (http.File, error) {
    type httpFile struct {
        *bytes.Reader
        *staticFile
    }
    return &httpFile{
        Reader:     bytes.NewReader(f.data),
        staticFile: f,
    }, nil
}

//implement the rest of os.FileInfo
func (f *staticFile) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func (f *staticFile) Stat() (os.FileInfo, error) {
    return f, nil
}

func (f *staticFile) Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func (f *staticFile) Name() string {
    return f.name
}

func (f *staticFile) Size() int64 {
    return int64(len(f.data))
}

func (f *staticFile) Mode() os.FileMode {
    return 0
}

func (f *staticFile) ModTime() time.Time {
    return time.Time{}
}

func (f *staticFile) IsDir() bool {
    return false
}

func (f *staticFile) Sys() interface{} {
    return f
}

func main() {

    const HTML = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
<p>Hello World</p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
`

    const CSS = `
p {
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
} 
`
    ASSETS := make(StaticFS)
    ASSETS["index.html"] = LoadAsset("index.html", HTML, ASSETS)
    ASSETS["style.css"] = LoadAsset("style.css", CSS, ASSETS)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(ASSETS))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Which compiles fine, but doesn't actually produce any results other than 404 page not found..

What I want to achieve is having a package in my app that allows me to make a map, embed some static content such as css and js in it and then serve it with http.Handle - Without using 3rd party tools like go-bindata, rice or anything else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: I don't see what's wrong after a quick glance.  I recommend starting from [the http.FileServer test](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0f72e79856d246af85c449f9e5a357ba751cd234/src/net/http/fs_test.go#L599-L662).   That code is known to work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) It compiles fine but the result is invariably "404 not found"... I'll have a look at the fileserver test thanks; although i think the problem is likely to be in the map - to filesystem part..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the main code we will need to look at, which comes from the source regarding `http.FileServer`:

```
func (f *fileHandler) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    upath := r.URL.Path
    if !strings.HasPrefix(upath, "/") {
        upath = "/" + upath
        r.URL.Path = upath
    }
    serveFile(w, r, f.root, path.Clean(upath), true)
}

// name is '/'-separated, not filepath.Separator.
func serveFile(w ResponseWriter, r *Request, fs FileSystem, name string, redirect bool) {
    const indexPage = "/index.html"

    // redirect .../index.html to .../
    // can't use Redirect() because that would make the path absolute,
    // which would be a problem running under StripPrefix
    if strings.HasSuffix(r.URL.Path, indexPage) {
        localRedirect(w, r, "./")
        return
    }

    f, err := fs.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        msg, code := toHTTPError(err)
        Error(w, msg, code)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    ...
}
```

In the `ServeHTTP` method, you will see a call to an unexported function.

```
serveFile(w, r, f.root, path.Clean(upath), true)
```

where `upath` is the request's URL path that is guaranteed to begin with "/".

In `serveFile`, `fs.Open(name)` is called, where `fs` is the `FileSystem` you provided and `name` is the argument we passed as `path.Clean(upath)`. Note that `path.Clean` is already being called, so you should not need to call this in your `prepare` method.

The takeaway here is that you are storing your "file names" without a preceding "/", which would represent they are in the root of the filesystem.

You can fix this two different ways.

1.

```
ASSETS["/index.html"] = LoadAsset("index.html", HTML, ASSETS)
ASSETS["/style.css"] = LoadAsset("style.css", CSS, ASSETS)
```

2.

```
func (fs StaticFS) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    if strings.HasPrefix(name, "/") {
        name = name[1:]
    }
    f, err := fs.prepare(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return f.File()
}
```

Comment: In fact, I can figure out this by add debug message. One question, `"/index.html"` not works as expected because browser treat `index.html` as `/`.

Comment: @Gavin - thank you so much for your thorough answer; it works now :) Have a terrific day :)

Comment: @YongHaoHu - indeed, when trying it out with 'other.html' and adding the leading slash it did actually work. Thanks for your help as well :)