# Default HTTP file server - modifications of the content

Tags: go, fileserver, go-http

How can I compose the default Go HTTP file server (serve if exists, show file listing otherwise) with additional HTML?

Sample `http.go` with default file server:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

Loading the default page (http://localhost:8090) gives something like:

```html
<pre><a href="LICENSE">LICENSE</a>
<a href="README.md">README.md</a>
<a href="studio.jpg">studio.jpg</a>
</pre>
```

I found it is declared at [`fs.go`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/net/http/fs.go;l=128).

I want to keep that section, but with my own header and footer (preferably without copying the `dirList` function and making small changes):

```html
<title>My files</title>

<pre><a href="LICENSE">LICENSE</a>
<a href="README.md">README.md</a>
<a href="studio.jpg">studio.jpg</a>
</pre>

<p>And that's all, folks!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21601539/8030651), you can implement own `FileSystem` for a `FileServer`

> This implementation is very buggy at best, and you should probably never ever use it, but it should show you how the FileSystem interface can be implemented for arbitrary 'files'.

```
type InMemoryFS map[string]http.File

type InMemoryFile struct {
    at   int64
    Name string
    data []byte
    fs   InMemoryFS
}

func NewFile(name string, data []byte) *InMemoryFile {
    return &InMemoryFile{at: 0,
        Name: name,
        data: data,
        fs:   make(InMemoryFS)}
}

// Implements the http.File interface
func (f *InMemoryFile) Close() error {
    return nil
}
func (f *InMemoryFile) Stat() (os.FileInfo, error) {
    return &InMemoryFileInfo{f}, nil
}
func (f *InMemoryFile) Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error) {
    return nil, nil
}
func (f *InMemoryFile) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    i := 0
    for f.at < int64(len(f.data)) && i < len(b) {
        b[i] = f.data[f.at]
        i++
        f.at++
    }
    return i, nil
}
func (f *InMemoryFile) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error) {
    switch whence {
    case 0:
        f.at = offset
    case 1:
        f.at += offset
    case 2:
        f.at = int64(len(f.data)) + offset
    }
    return f.at, nil
}

type InMemoryFileInfo struct {
    file *InMemoryFile
}

// Implements os.FileInfo
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) Name() string       { return s.file.Name }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) Size() int64        { return int64(len(s.file.data)) }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) Mode() os.FileMode  { return os.ModeTemporary }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) ModTime() time.Time { return time.Time{} }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) IsDir() bool        { return false }
func (s *InMemoryFileInfo) Sys() interface{}   { return nil }
```

```
// CustomFsDecorator: is `http.FileSystem` decorator
type CustomFsDecorator struct {
    http.FileSystem
}

func (fs CustomFsDecorator) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    file, err := fs.FileSystem.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    info, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if info.IsDir() {
        return file, nil
    }

    b, err := io.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    // add header's lines
    _, err = buf.Write([]byte("<title>My files</title>\n"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    _, err = buf.Write(b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // add footer's lines
    _, err = buf.Write([]byte("\n<p>And that's all, folks!</p>"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return NewFile(info.Name(), buf.Bytes()), nil
}
```

```
func Test(t *testing.T) {
    cfsys := CustomFsDecorator{FileSystem: http.Dir("./static")}
    fsys := http.FileServer(cfsys)

    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/some.html", nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    fsys.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    res := w.Result()
    defer func() {
        _ = res.Body.Close()
    }()

    data, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("expected error to be nil got %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

```
<title>My files</title>
<pre><a href="LICENSE">LICENSE</a>
<a href="README.md">README.md</a>
<a href="studio.jpg">studio.jpg</a>
</pre>
<p>And that's all, folks!</p>
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/lRqzXsuGbud)</kbd>